# React native android fontFamily cant change or does not effect

Tags: android, react-native, text, fonts, font-awesome

RNN 0.57, emulator android.

I am trying to change `fontFamily`, it seems whatever the `fontFamily` is the `Font` never change.

```
<View>
   <Text style={{fontSize:24, fontFamily: 'Feather', color:'black'}}>Title Text Test</Text>
 </View>
```

The result is always this font

[image]

I tried Roboto, Feather, FontAwesome, etc but no change, still displaying the same font as a screenshot.

[image]

Any idea what's wrong? Is there any default font override my style?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e

Comment: The fonts I tried is already in android/app/src/main/assets/fonts folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of those fonts are icon fonts, linked via `react-native-vector-icons`. To use them, you should use [their api](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather'
```

If you want to use custom fonts, you need to link the fonts with your project manually. First find some fonts and put them somewhere in your project root; I usually put mine in `./src/assets/fonts`

In your `package.json` add:

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "./src/assets/fonts"
  ]
}
```

Then run `react-native link` and you will be able to use those custom fonts.